# Mysql forcibly order by exact value

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

Need help with mysql request.

I make a request and I want to order result by the field ID.

ID for exemple: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

But I need that it would be ordered like this: 6,3,1,2,4,5,7,8,9

Is there any solution in mysql  to forcibly put ID=6 in 1st place, ID=3 in 2nd...?

or I want the impossible)

Answer (score 0):

Use **`CASE`** expression in **`ORDER BY`** clause.

**Query**

```
select * from `your_table_name`
order by case `id` when 6 then 1 when 3 then 2 else 3 end, `id`;
```

**[Find a demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/173d9d/1)**

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
ORDER BY FIELD(id, 6,3,1,2,4,5,7,8,9)
```

The [`FIELD`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_field) function returns the position of the first value in the remaining list.